# Connecting from android wear to phone

Tags: java, android, wear-os

i am trying to get connection between android wear and an android device. i can get the phone log responding but i cannot get the watch log to communicate back. the phone connects but i need to watch to connect and communicate back.

Here are my classes

Moblie

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// for broad communication
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API).addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks).build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks mConnectionCallbacks = new
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, mMessageListener);
                Log.d("TAG::::", "IN onConnected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            }
        };


MessageApi.MessageListener mMessageListener = new MessageApi.MessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(messageEvent.getData());
        final int value = byteBuffer.getInt();

        Log.d("TAG::::", "received good") ;

    }
};


}
```

Wear

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private TextView mTextView;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;   // for broad communication
Node mNode;

float [] values;
Sensor acceler;
SensorManager sm;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);

        }
    });

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


}



GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks mConnectionCallbacks = new GoogleApiClient
        .ConnectionCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result = Wearable.NodeApi
                        .getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();

                List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if (nodes.size() > 0) {
                    mNode = nodes.get(0);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }
};


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    values[0] = event.values[0];
    sendToPhone(8);

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

private void sendToPhone(final int value) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array();
            Log.d("TAG:::", "JIMMMMMMMMy");
            Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, mNode.getId(),
                    "/newgolf", bytes).await();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

Comment: Check the [Sending and Syncing Data](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) docs because it mentions something about [Accessing the Wearable Data Layer](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/accessing.html) where it says that A Wear app can communicate with a phone app using the Data Layer API.